# Fail @Valid annotated methods on runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Request implements RequestDto {

private final req ipwRequest = new IpwRequestMetadataDto();

    @Valid
    @Override
    public String getRequestId() {
        if (isRequestIdNull() && req.getRequestId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!isRequestIdNull() && req.getRequestId() != null && req.getRequestId().length() > 0) {
            return req.getRequestId();
        }

        String errorMessage = "Request id should " +
                (isRequestIdNull() ? "" : "not ") +
                "be null";
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(errorMessage, Collections.emptySet());
    }

    protected abstract boolean isRequestIdNull();
}
```

This class can be overridden by two other classes each overriding `isRequestIdNull`.

I try to test that this works fine by using a validator like this:

```
@Test
public void testCreateRequest() {
    var dto = new CreateRequest();
    dto.setRequestId("11111");

    Set<ConstraintViolation<CreateRequest>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(dto);

    // Assert
    assertNotEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
}
```

The getRequestId is called when the validator is called but instead of adding to the `constraintViolations`, it just throws the exception and crashes.

How can I add to the constraintViolations instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the constraintViolations as a parameter to the getRequestId, and have a flag whether to throw the exception or add to the list of constraintViolations inside the function getRequestId

Comment: No, the method is a getter, cant do that.